# Adobe Pro 9 form not digatally signable in Adobe Reader x

Tags: digital-signature

I created a form in Adobe Pro 9 with a digital signature block.  When a Adobe Reader X user tries to sign document it does nothing?  How do I correct without upgrading to Adobe Pro X?